# Bing Map on the iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, bing-maps

How can I integrate bing map on the iPad or iPhone business application ?

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: I found a post about that on google. http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2008/11/13/developing-virtual-earth-iphone-applications-with-objective-c.aspx Did you already tried?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to do this? You can of course overlay a map over the google map client. I've seen this done with Open street map, not seen Bing but the theory means it should work!

Answer (score 3):

I write a `javascript wrapper` from BING Api to ObjectiveC.
It's not the best solution, but it works.

> Objective-C offfer a method **to call
>   directly javascript from your code**.
>
> You can use
>   `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`
>   from your `UIWebView` to call all of
>   the js functions (zoom in, setmapType,
>   etc...).
>
> Your UIWebView **must be** a html page
>   that contains a *basic map*.

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var map = null;

         function GetMap()
         {
            map = new VEMap('myMap');
            map.LoadMap(new VELatLong(45.46347, 9.19404), 10 ,'h' ,false);
            map.HideDashboard();
            map.SetMapStyle(VEMapStyle.Road);
            map.SetZoomLevel(10);
         }   
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
      <div id='myMap' style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:320px; height:460px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Bing reference (http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/)

After a day you can reach this result:

[image: http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2010/10/iphone-microsoft-bing-map-iphone-ipad/]

Here an example of wrapped js (where `map` is a JS variable on your html page!):

```
- (void) setZoom:(int)level {
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"map.setZoom(%d);", level]];
}
- (void) setCenterPoint:(NSString*)point {
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[@"map.setCenterPoint(%@);", point]];
}
- (void) zoomIn {
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"map.zoomIn();"];
}
- (void) zoomOut {
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"map.zoomOut();"];
}
```

You can use touch gestures and... much more!

Hope this helps!

Alberto.

Comment: Paska, How do you plot pins in this map, add annotations?

Comment: @Krishnan i don't remember, but here you can find all that you find: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/

Comment: is there any problem in terms of memory when this is used is a UIwebview?

Comment: No, no memory issue at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Bing Maps now has an iOS SDK so you can use it natively in your iOS apps:

[New Bing Maps iOS SDK](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/05/05/new-bing-maps-ios-sdk.aspx)